# html input pattern validation in angular 4 validate if string contains only pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, html, angular, validation

I have to validate an input in html using pattern in angular 4
my pattern is

```
pat = /^(\s*#?\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(am|pm|AM|PM)\s*,?)+/;
```

and in html

```
<input type="text" [pattern]="precisionTimePattern" #precisionSlotValue="ngModel" name="slot-value-precision" 
            id="slotValuePrecision" class="input-minimal" 
            [ngModel]="formObject.precisionType.slotValue" 
            [class.invalid]="(!precisionSlotValue.valid && precisionSlotValue.touched) || (!precisionSlotValue.valid && f.submitted)">
```

to match string only if "12:00 AM, 2:0 PM #3:00 PM" 
 
but it also validate if user input "12:00 AM, 2:0 PM #3:00 PM  ajkcsbkajk"

Comment: Add `$` at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a dollar sign (end of string match)

```
pat = /^(\s*#?\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(am|pm|AM|PM)\s*,?)+$/;
```